# create image from layer containing the polylines

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef, draw2d

I made an swt.graphics.Image object of a draw2d Layer containing draw2d polylines and few other figures like circles ellipses etc. I made a jpeg file from this Image object, all I can see are the ellipses, circles etc but no figures drawn using draw2d polylines(connection arrows, PolygonShapes etc) are present in the final jpeg file. I want the polylines also to be plotted and visible in the final jpeg file. Any ideas how i can do this? I have tried putting the Layer in a shell. But I have to display(which i should not do) the shell to the user using shell.open() only then the polyline shapes are visible in the final jpeg file. I guess the shell.open() forces the drawing of the shell and its children ( the Layer, the polylines etc). Is there are any workaround for not showing the shell but force the drawing on Layer for polylines?

Thanks and Regards
Bharath

Comment: How exactly are you creating the image? Your connections are probably on a different layer than the rest of your figures. Are you sure you're drawing both layers (or rather their common parent)?

Comment: The circles and ellipse are on Figure which is kept inside a Layer. The polylines are kept on a different Figure which is also kept in the same Layer. As you have mentioned may be only the Figure which is on top is drawn and rest aren't. There is only one Layer and I am placing this Layer in a FigureCanvas. I am not calling an explicit draw or anything of that sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this. I called the validate() on the Layer. previously I was calling  redraw(),Layout() etc on the FigureCanvas on which the Layer is present and there was no change. Now after calling the validate() on the Layer it seems to work.